# unable to invoke javascript function fome C# webview windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, windows, webview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

i am unable to trigger the js fuction from my main page.i guess the issue is that i have multiple js file for one html page

my main page code is

```
 WebViewControl.InvokeScript("NativeHook.getContactListCb", new[] { finalstring });
```

my htmlpage code

```
<html>
<head>

    <......
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../core/js/UrlUtils.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../core/js/NativeHook.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../core/js/NetworkManager.js"></script>...</body>
```

my Nativehook.js code

```
function getContactListCb(str) {
    alert(str);

}
```

can some one pleas help on this issue.Thanks in advance.